GLMM with interaction terms between two circular predictor variables?
I am running a GLMM to see if several weather and nest box covariates influence occupancy (binary linear response). I would like to include two circular predictors (wind direction and box entrance orientation) in my model, as well as their interaction (plus other predictors such as temp, box area, etc.). The hypothesis being that birds will choose to occupy boxes with an orientation facing the same way the wind is blowing (ex. E facing box when W winds).
In my current model, I have both wind direction and box orientation converted from degrees to radians using sin and cos functions, resulting in 4 'linear' predictors. Therefore, for the interaction terms I am multiplying the linear EW components and multiplying the linear NS components, with these interaction terms added to my other predictor variables and random effect.
Is this the correct approach? I am just having trouble finding information on interactions between two circular predictor variables.

Might it be better to model the difference between the box orientation and wind direction, along with one or the other, with no interaction? It's not clear that the product of the directions (an interaction term is just a product, after all) is going to be very helpful or easy to interpret.
